# Azure App Service: Create hybrid connection endpoint API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to create an App Service Hybrid Connection Endpoint via an API, either .NET or REST? It seems that it is only possible through the portal.
I know there is an option to do this with the old BizTalk service hybrid connections, but I need this for the new (v2) App Service Hybrid connections.

Comment: I also haven't found any way to do it from official document. I suggest you do it through Azure portal and record the HTTP traffic using web browser developer tool or Fiddler. You could find the REST URL from the http traffic.  On my side, I found the REST URL is like this, PUT https ://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group}/providers/Microsoft.Relay/namespaces/{servicebus-name}/HybridConnections/[connection-name]?api-version=2016-07-01 HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible now.
Need to use Azure Relay Management Library (in preview currently) + Use REST to update a Web App.

Note: To be able to use it in the HCM, you will also need to add "endpoint" property to the Relay. I have everything working, so it's possible.